# Handling module dependency inheritance in ui-router states

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, module, dependencies, angular-ui-router

I have a website based on [ui-router's nested state/view](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) in order to resolve and share resources widely through my solution.

The states have parent/child relationships with multiple modules and controllers, which inherit each other's dependencies.

My question is how should those dependencies **between modules** be properly handled. Initially I added each dependency that a module needs to itself, but I later noticed that I can add the dependencies to its parent state without any complications.

Naturally, recurrence came to mind. There were many cases in which all children state's modules use the same dependencies, so what if I simply add them to the parent once?

The JS/CSS files are obviously loaded once, but it is the **module dependencies** that make me wonder, since the controllers I use are of different modules.